# Laravel routes not working when installed in a subfolder

Tags: php, laravel, nginx

I need help running Laravel from a subfolder in our dev environment.

Our devs have to clone the main site repo into a folder under their subdomain like so:

https://developer.example.com/branch/ points to /var/www/html/developer/branch/

Examples:

- https://dev1.example.com/laravel8/
- https://dev2.example.com/ticket-12345/
- https://dev3.example.com/some-other-branch/

We currently run a homegrown PHP app that this works just fine with, trying to migrate to Laravel (testing with v8.0) I'm finding all routes are broken unless they contain the subfolder name which is not feasible.

```
// Doesn't work
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});

// Works
Route::get('/laravel8', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});

// Doesn't work
Route::get('/welcome', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});

// Works
Route::get('/laravel8/welcome', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});

// Legacy route handler (Works)
Route::any('/{path?}', LegacyController::class)->where('path', '.*');
```

I've tried setting the APP_URL to https://dev1.example.com/branch/ which does nothing.

Our NGINX config rewrites requests like so

https://developer.example.com/branch/ -> https://developer.example.com/branch/public/index.php

```
server {
        server_tokens off;

        listen 80;
        autoindex off;
        server_name dev1.example.com;
        root /var/www/html/dev1;

        access_log /home/dev1/nginx-access.log;
        error_log /home/dev1/nginx-error.log debug;
        rewrite_log on;

        index index.php index.html;
        client_max_body_size 100M;

        # Rewrite legacy app URLs
        # /branch/control.php/login/ -> /branch/login/
        #if ($uri ~* "^/([A-Za-z0-9\-\_]+)/control\.php/(.*)$") {
        location ~* ^/([A-Za-z0-9\-\_]+)/control\.php/(.*)$ {
                rewrite ^/([A-Za-z0-9\-\_]+)/control\.php/(.*)$ /$1/$2; # Works
        }

        #include /etc/nginx/includes/dev_laravel.conf;

        # Capture the subfolder name to a variable
        location ~* ^/(?<appid>[A-Za-z0-9\-\_]+) {

                alias /var/www/html/dev1/$appid/public;
                try_files $uri $uri/ @rewapp;


                # Sometimes only contains /branch/login/ other times contains /branch/public/index.php/login/
                location ~* ^/([A-Za-z0-9\-\_]+)/(.*\.php)(/.*) {

                        fastcgi_index index.php;

                        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_NAME $2;
                        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /var/www/html/dev1/$1/public/$2;
                        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $3;

                        keepalive_timeout 0;

                        fastcgi_connect_timeout 120;
                        fastcgi_send_timeout 3600;
                        fastcgi_read_timeout 3600;
                        fastcgi_buffers 4 256k;
                        fastcgi_buffer_size 256k;
                        fastcgi_intercept_errors off;

                        #fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME    $document_root$script;
                        #fastcgi_param  PATH_INFO          $path_info;
                        fastcgi_param  PATH_TRANSLATED    $document_root$fastcgi_path_info;
                        fastcgi_param  HTTPS          on;

                        fastcgi_param  REQUEST_METHOD   $request_method;
                        fastcgi_param  CONTENT_TYPE     $content_type;
                        fastcgi_param  CONTENT_LENGTH   $content_length;


                        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php-fpm/www.sock;

                        include fastcgi_params;
                }

                # Necessary for static files,
                # or may fall to another location with incorrect path
                # Add more extensions like PDF if necessary
                location ~* ^/([A-Za-z0-9\-\_]+)/(.+\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|css|svg|png|js|map|ico|html|xml|txt|woff|woff2))$ {
                        alias /var/www/html/dev1/$1/public;
                        try_files $uri /$2 =404;
                }
        }

        # Rewrite URL for Laravel
        # https://www.example.com/branch/login/ -> https://www.example.com/branch/public/index.php/login/
        location @rewapp {
                #rewrite ^/([A-Za-z0-9\-\_]+)/(?:control\.php/)?(.*)$ /$1/index.php/$2 last; # Try to eliminate control.php (Throws file not found)
                rewrite ^/([A-Za-z0-9\-\_]+)/(.*)$ /$1/index.php/$2 last;
        }
}
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: So where are all the other routes? When does `Route::any` kick in? That route sounds problematic and definitely should be last on the list

Comment: There aren't any other routes yet because the routes aren't working as is. The only one that does work is for the LegacyController. The idea is we are porting our old app into Laravel using the instructions [here](https://tighten.com/insights/converting-a-legacy-app-to-laravel/). The wildcard route will catch any "legacy" routes until each one is converted to Laravel controller, then the route will be added.